# Use JSON with HighCharts and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I'm lost with the JSON format and HighCharts. I tried many technics of forums but the result is not good.

My problem :

**1-** OnClick Ajax call a PHP file who generate a JSON like that :

```
{"col0":["TROUILLE","BOUILLE"],"col1":[4,1],"col2":[6.35,1.59]}
```

**2-** I Would Like to choose for example "col1" for *xAxys* and "col2" for *yAxis* so that my test

`param_connection` contain the conection of DB parameters

`options` contain the options parameters of my graphics :

```
$.post(
                    "file_json.php",
                    param_connection,
                    function(json) {
                        options.credits = {enabled: false};
                        options.series = json;
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);}, 
                    "json");
```

Today my result is null...

Thank you for your help.

Geo-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your json object just isn't the format highcharts wants.

`{"x":value, "y":value2}`

You'll have to iterate over your returned JSON object, to get it in the format highcharts wants:

```
$.post(
  "file_json.php",
  param_connection,
  function(json) {
    var jsonData = [];
    for(var i=0, row; row = json[i]; i++){
      jsonData.push({"x": row['col1'], "y": row['col2']});
    }
    options.credits = {enabled: false};
    options.series = jsonData;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);}, 
  "json");
```

Comment: Yes, it's okay if I write : "name": row['col1'], "data": row['col2']. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah, great! If you liked this answer, can you mark it accepted? To help other people find the answer, and to help my reputation :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Of course, sorry... I can't vote up because I've the message : "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"